# How to load an image in C# Winforms from an URL without application freezing?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have some PictureBox objects in foreach.
It loops all the PictureBoxes and loads images from the internet for them. Each PictureBox has a different picture downloading.
It works good, but the problem is the application freezes until all the images load.
Is there a way to make them appear one by one and not all at the same time?

Code:

```
index++;                
lpb[index].Load(url); 
//lpb is a list of PictureBoxes (List<PictureBox>)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `Load`. As the docs explain you should also set the [WaitOnLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.waitonload?view=netcore-3.1) property to false.

The [LoadProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadprogresschanged?view=netcore-3.1) and [LoadCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadcompleted?view=netcore-3.1) events can be used to track progress.

From the doc example:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Ensure WaitOnLoad is false.
    pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = false;

    // Load the image asynchronously.
    pictureBox1.LoadAsync(@"http://localhost/print.gif");
}
```